# Как сделать обертку для System.out.println путем передачи ссылки на метод?

Tags: java, функциональное-программирование

В качестве академического интереса хочу сделать обертку для System.out.println, при помощи передачи ссылки на метод println в обертку println_. Подскажите, как реализовать эту обертку?

```
public class Class1
{
    static void println_(???) {
        ???
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        println_(System.out::println, "qwerty");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.out.println()` - это обычный [`Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html), и свой метод можно переписать как дженерик:

```java
static <T> void println_(Consumer<T> printer, T obj) {
    printer.accept(obj);
}

println_(System.out::println, "abcd");
// -> abcd
```

Comment: а по каким признакам определить что это Consumer?

Comment: `Consumer` - принимает некоторое значение и ничего не возвращает (метод с возвращаемым типом `void`, например, обычный сеттер), `Supplier` - не имеет входных аргументов, но возвращает некоторое значение (конструкторы или геттеры)